# iOS: On calling reloadRowsAtIndexPaths, the didEndDisplayingCell is called twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Whenever I call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` ; the `didEndDisplayingCell` method is called two times. Why is this happening?

I have implemented following delegate methods of UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource:

- `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`
- `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`
- `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath`

The reason why I implemented `didEndDisplayingCell` is that, I want to detach the Firebase listener.

**Here is what I implemented inside** `didEndDisplayingCell`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
// detach the listener for the cell at path index indexPath

  CustomCell* customCell = (CustomCell*)(cell);
  [customCell detachListener]; 
}
```

Whenever a cell listens to an updated data it fires a method in the ViewController which reloads the tableViewCell. Here is how I implemented that method:

```
-(void)refreshCellWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath andData:(CustomData*)data{

  [self.dataArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:data];

  [self.tableView beginUpdates];
  [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
  [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

When this method executes UITableView delegate methods are called as per the following sequence:

1. `numberOfRowsInSection`
2. `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
3. `didEndDisplayingCell`
4. `didEndDisplayingCell`

**Why is this `didEndDisplayingCell` method is called second time?** Please help me through this.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the value of `indexPath` for the duplicate calls to `didEndDisplayingCell` ... *might* help point to the reason/solution.

Comment: @DonMag, thanks for the quick response. Well the `indexPath` for the duplicate calls to `didEndDisplayingCell ` is the same.

Comment: Hmmm... does the indexPath make sense? Does it look like that cell *should* be getting removed?

Comment: The indexPath I passed to `reloadRowAtIndexPath`, same is obtained in both calls of `didEndDisplayingCell`. AFAIK when we call `reloadRowAtIndexPath`, the tableView removes the cell at that indexPath and add new cell their. But that should not be called 2 times. Also I found it strange that `didEndDisplayingCell ` is called after `cellForRowAtIndexPath `.

Comment: What happens if you remove the calls to `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`?

Comment: Same scenario. No change.

Comment: Too much to post as a comment, but... Quick searching and quick testing... looks like this is a "bug" or "odd behavior". I'm curious... when you do:

    `CustomCell* customCell = (CustomCell*)(cell);`

in `didEndDisplayingCell` -- do you get a valid reference to a CustomCell each time? If so, is the Listener also still valid?

Comment: @DonMag Yes I double checked it. Both time the customCell reference is same and valid.

Comment: Do you have header or multiple sections in your tableView ?

Comment: @iOSGeek, No I do not have the header and also I am not using multiple sections. Just single type of cell.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround:

Instead of

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Use (swift):

```
reloadCounter += 1
CATransaction.begin()
tableView.beginUpdates()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    self.reloadCounter -= 1
}
tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)], with: .none)
tableView.endUpdates()
CATransaction.commit()
```

reloadCounter is an ivar.

and in didEndDisplaying:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (reloadCounter == 0) {
        self.output.didEndDisplaying(viewModel: dataProvider.items[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```